# How to Remove all Feed Links from Wordpress CPT Only?

Tags: wordpress, rss

I need to remove all of the RSS feed links from a Custom Post Type in WP. I have tried this in my child theme:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
```

It successfully removes the links from the entire site, but I need the feed links on the default posts. I do however need to remove them from my CPT.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking whether you're on cpt page:

```
  if( is_post_type_archive('my-cpt') || is_singular('my-cpt') ) {

      remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
      remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a combination of the submitted answer here and [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162168/remove-action-conditionally-for-custom-post-type-not-working).

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'lf_custom_cpt_display');
function lf_custom_cpt_display() {
    if ( is_post_type_archive('my-cpt') || is_singular('my-cpt') ): {
        remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
        remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
    }
    endif;
}
```

Replace `my-cpt` with the name of your custom post type.